# Where does the Windows for Arm build downloaded by Parallels desktop on Macs with Apple silicon come from?

Tags: windows, parallels-desktop, apple-silicon

When you install Windows 11 through Parallels 18 on a Mac with Apple silicon, it downloads a Windows 11 image that contains a build of Windows for Arm CPUs. Last time I did this, it downloaded and installed the following:

| - | - |
| --- | --- |
| Edition | Windows 11 Home |
| Version | 21H2 |
| OS build | 22000.1641 |
| Experience | Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.1641.0 |

Where did Parallels download that from?
Do they have a special agreement with Microsoft to download a stable build of Windows 11 for Arm from an endpoint that is not available to others? The only place I can seem to find an ISO with Windows for Arm is the Windows Insiders Program, but those are preview builds, not the stable ones.

I'd like to download a stable version to use with VMWare Fusion, which now supports Apple silicon as well.

Comment: I assume you would be using a "Windows 11 on ARM Insider Preview VHDX" file when creating the virtual machine. Why do you think this should be an ISO and not a preview release?

Comment: Well, @DavidAnderson, the build number of the actual preview as downloaded from Microsoft Windows Insider was 22598.1, while the build number for the Windows Parallels downloaded on the same day was 22000.1641. They seem to be very far from each other. Also, Windows insider only has beta and dev channels. There is no stable channel. If Parallels were downloading from a dev or beta channel, I reckon there would have been some kind of warning at the time of installation.

I keep wondering if Parallels would have been able to get Microsoft to prepare a build just for them.

Comment: According to this [Microsoft website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/february-21-2023-kb5022905-os-build-22000-1641-preview-af27b509-b478-415b-be20-3747f477f3fe). The current build for Windows 11 version 21H2 is 22000.1641. The builds for Windows 11 version 22H2 start at 22621, which is greater than 22598.1. Evidently, getting an ARM Windows 11 to upgrade from version 22H1 to 22H2 can be a bit tricky.